# AWS policy to deny access to AWS resource, if the requester is not the resource owner

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an AWS account used for training that has around 20 users. They all currently have Admin access. I'm trying to figure out a way to add some safety. In theory they all know enough to not delete each others resource, but that doesn't stop accidents from happening. Right now everyone can delete/terminate each others resources. I want to build a policy that allows a user to do anything with a resource that they created, but I do not want them to be able to modify (mostly delete/terminate) another users resource. Normally I would just deny access to a specific resource, but in this case since resources are built and destroyed daily or weekly, it's to much to try and manage. I've looked at denying access based of ownerId of the resource, and the users ARN. I have been unable to find a way to get the OwnerId inside the policy statement so I can do a string compare on them. I'm currently thinking that what I'm trying to do is currently not possible, looking for any ideas you guys might have to accomplish this. I have this policy.

```
"Statement": {
"Effect": "deny",
"Action": "*",
"Resource": "*",
"Condition": {"StringNotEquals": {"Resource:OwnerId": "AccountID"}}
```

Where AccountID is the users AccountID, I will have to create a policy for each user doing it this way. But trying to find out how to get the OwnerId of the resource that user is trying to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create an IAM policy that restricts access based on who "created the resource". This is because the identity of the creator is not stored on a resource. AWS merely checks that a person has permission to create something and then does it. The resource then belongs to the account, not a specific user.

A few options:

- Give each person a separate account: This guarantees separation. Accounts can be joined via Consolidated Billing to give one monthly bill. However, it makes it hard to "share" resources.
- Use tags to identify owners: Ask for or enforce the use of tags that identify who created the resource. Then, create IAM rules that only permit certain API calls if the owner tag is set to their identifier. If there is a resource without an owner tag, delete it! However, this requires your own code to perform the enforcement, either using AWS Config Rules (via Lambda) or your own code that regularly calls APIs. Also, some tags can only be applied after resources are created (eg EC2 instances) so it would need to allow a grace period.
- Don't let them create resources directly: Instead, provide a front-end that creates the resources on their behalf, which also tags resources. It can even delete resources after a certain period of time.